# Archive directory structure without file contents

Tags: unix, backup, tar, archiving

I would like to create an archive capturing the entire structure of a directory, including subdirectories and files. Preferably preserving file attributes such as modification time. The archive *shouldn't contain any content* of files, though.

In other words, the effect I'm trying to achieve is the same as if I created an exact copy of the directory, trimmed sizes of all files in it to zero, and then archived it with `tar`.

I looked at various `tar` options and it doesn't seem to support what I need. I thought there would be something like `--use-compress-program=true` but that one is applied to the entire archive, not to individual files, unfortunately. I haven't spotted any relevant `rsync` options either.

Is there a way how to create such archive with unix tool?

Comment: A special-purpose script using `touch` and `mkdir` could do this.

Comment: Right Thomas, using `ls -R` could get the original structure. Lots of potential problems with file names containing funny characters, newlines, etc.

Comment: No: "ls -R" would not be useful for a general-purpose solution. "find" would be an improvement, but also self-limiting (I'd just write it in Perl).

Comment: See also https://github.com/mifeet/DirStructureCopy

Answer (score 2):

at first sight (w/o date of file/directory) :

```
find data -type d -exec echo mkdir -p {} \;  | ( cd tmp7 ; bash )
find data -type f -exec echo touch {} \; | ( cd tmp7 ; bash )
```

where

- data is your source
- tmp7 your destination

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old, and my answer doesn't meet the “with Unix tool” criteria, but for what it's worth, the Windows synchronizing tool Robocopy can do just that with a simple /CREATE switch (it creates the whole file tree from the source to the destination, with 0 length files but all timestamps preserved, even those of directories if the /DCOPY:T switch is also used). That's one instance where a Windows tool can easily do some trick which is apparently not possible by simple means on a Linux/Unix system.